# How to replace certain values in the dataframe using tidyverse in R?

Tags: tidyverse, tidy

There are some values in my dataset(df) that needs to be replaced with correct values e.g.,

| Height | Disease | Weight>90kg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.58 | 1 | 0 |
| 1.64 | 0 | 1 |
| 1.67 | 1 | 0 |
| 52 | 0 | 1 |
| 67 | 0 | 0 |

I want to replace the first three values as '158', '164' & '167'. I want to replace the next as 152 and 167 (adding 1 at the beginning).

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
data_clean <- function(df) {
df[height==1.58] <- 158
df}
data_clean(df)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `recode` you can explicitly recode the values:

```r
df <- mutate(df, height = recode(height, 
                                 1.58 = 158, 
                                 1.64 = 164, 
                                 1.67 = 167, 
                                 52 = 152, 
                                 67 = 167))
```

However, this obviously is a manual process and not ideal for a case with many values that need recoding.

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
df <- mutate(df, height = case_when(
  height < 2.5 ~ height * 100,
  height < 100 ~ height + 100
)
```

This would really depend on the makeup of your data but for the example given it would work. Just be careful with what your assumptions are. Could also have used `is.double` and 'is.integer`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @geoff. I tried using recode but it returns an error saying, unexpected '=' in & unexpected ',' in.  I have tidyverse package loaded.

Comment: Probably expects factors only. Bit more verbose but essentially the same as recode is `mutate(df, height = case_when(height == 1.58 ~ 158, height == 1.64 ~ 164, ...`

Comment: Thanks @geoff. This one worked but it changes all the other correct values in *height* to 'NA'. Height is <dbl>. Can you suggest a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yep, when using `case_when` you need to explicitly name all conditions otherwise the other values will be NA. The typical way to do this is add `TRUE ~ height` do the end of your `case_when`. In other words, if you reach this condition, simply return the actual value.